# Select from table with current user's schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, database-schema

I am working in a database where each user has a table in their schema called FindResults

eg: MyDatabase.User1.FindResults, MyDatabase.User2.FindResults, etc.

If I run a SELECT query on this table while logged in as one of the users it works just fine. However, I have a stored procedure (MyDatabase.dbo.ReadFindResults) that tries to run a SELECT query on this table, it fails because it tries to read MyDatabase.dbo.FindResults (does not exist).  I have gotten around this by using dynamic SQL, but I was hoping there was a way to avoid this.

Is there a way to tell the stored procedure to use the current user's schema or perhaps something to change the scope to allow it to find the table I want?

EDIT: Here is the code for the stored procedure

```
-- Returns the IDs contained in the given find results set
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReadFindResults]
    @resultsid int  -- The ID of the results set
AS
BEGIN

   SELECT objectid FROM FindResults WHERE resultsid = @resultsid

END
GO
```

Comment: If you have tables with the same name under different schemas, why not have separate stored procedures too? You can leave out the schema but this is a terribly misleading way to code and can lead to very frustrating troubleshooting sessions.

Comment: Perhaps you could use `EXECUTE AS` if individual users are connecting to the database using their own logins/schemas.

Comment: @ulty4life not sure how `EXECUTE AS` will help in this specific case - can you provide an example? Who would you set the procedure to execute as, that would allow a hard-coded reference to `dbo.sometable` actually change to `theirschema.sometable`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand In this case, it is not a hard coded reference to dbo.FindResults.  In the simplest example it is just `SELECT * FROM FindResults`

Comment: @ulty4life This does not seem to work.  I tried it with `EXECUTE AS CALLER`, `EXECUTE AS SELF`, and even `EXECUTE AS OWNER`.  All of them still return the results from the DBO version of the table, not the currently logged in user's table.  This did sound promising though.

Comment: If you have a table in each schema, maybe you'll adopt to have a stored procedure for each schema?

Answer (score 0):

In your stored procedure you can say:

```
SELECT cols FROM MyDatabase..FindResults;
```

(Leaving out the schema name.)

However this seems very error-prone, and IMHO you should either have separate, schema-bound stored procedures as well, or a single table with a column to indicate whose row it is.

A hack could be to execute as the username:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(255) = N'EXECUTE AS USER = N''' + SUSER_SNAME() + '''';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
SELECT whatever FROM Findresults;
```

But I haven't had the opportunity to test this (you're better equipped to test in your scenario anyway).

It still seems like a remarkably avoidable problem in the first place, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: This does not seem to work.  When I run the stored procedure, it still returns results for the dbo version of the table.  I also tried running the SP as dbo.ReadFindResults, MyDatabase..ReadFindResults, and just ReadFindResults.

Also, I can't do this either as I also have several different databases.  Each company has their own database for the program, so I can't hard code the database name into the stored procedure.

Comment: @Nosfera2 don't understand. If your program knows who the company is, and knows which database their data is in, why do your queries need to have the database name at all? Just connect directly to the right database.

Comment: And typically that is exactly what we do.  We connect to the database and call stored procedures and they return the proper results.  Unfortunately, this one table is special and each user has their own.  This works fine for normal calls, but when called from a stored procedure, it always returns results for the DBO version of the table.

Comment: Using `EXECUTE AS USER` does not appear to work either.  I would love for this to be one table with a column to reference the user, but I am not the one who can make that call.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamic SQL like this:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1024) = "SELECT something FROM [userName].someTable"
DECLARE @userName NVARCHAR(255) = SUSER_SNAME()
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, "[userName]", @userName)

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

That too is a hakish way of doing that query. More reading about dynamic SQL here: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Im at home right now and do not have access to a SQL Server. I will edit my post in the morning when Im at work if needed.